# android implementing AlertDialogSamples class

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

Thanks for being a terrific resource, I have a question about implementing the android sdk apidemo AlertDialogSamples.java. Basically i want to add the AlertDialogSamples class into my app and to call on it for various alertdialogs (i.e., `DIALOG_YES_NO_MESSAGE`, `DIALOG_PROGRESS`, ...) from any of my activities. I am surprised all online examples have the alertdialog code within each activity class.

I tried a few iterations on this idea:

```
public class My1Activity extends SherlockActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   ...
   AlertDialogSamples alert = new AlertDialogSamples();
   ...
   private void changeEmailCommand(){
         alert.showAlertDialog(My1Activity.this, DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY, title);
```

and then:

```
public class AlertDialogSamples extends Activity {
   ...
public void showAlertDialog(Context context, int i, String title) {
        showAlertDialog(context, i, title);
  ... (rest is existing code and modifying the .setTitle to accept title message)
    }
```

and had no luck getting the alertdialog to appear (just crashes)

Is there a way to do it with intents? asynch?

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code to show progress dialogs:

1. Create a utility class with Static methods.
2. Call them from your activity when you want to display a dialogue ex: Utility.showActionIndicator("Your message", Acitivty.this); and Utility.dismissActionIndicator();

You can take help of this example and try your luck.

Code updated to add utility method to show alert dialog - Just call Utility.showAlertDialog(YourActivity.this)

**Update:** (Tip - Add Morfy A Wounded Lion's method to this class - Thanks Morfy A Wounded Lion for that code. Its awesome)

```
public class Utility {

    private static ProgressDialog   actionIndicator = null;
    private static AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder   = null;

    private Utility() {

    }

    public static void showAlertDialog(Activity activity) {

        if (alertDialogBuilder == null) {
            alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        }
            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                    }
                  })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();

    }

    public static void showActionIndicator(String message,Activity activity) {

        if (actionIndicator == null) {
            actionIndicator = 
            new ProgressDialog(activity);
        }
        actionIndicator.setCancelable(false);
        actionIndicator.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        actionIndicator.setMessage(message);
        if (!actionIndicator.isShowing()) {
            try {
                actionIndicator.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.d("exception","something went wrong",e);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Dialog is showing");
    }

    public static void changeActionIndicatorMessage(String message) {

        if (actionIndicator != null && actionIndicator.isShowing()) {
            actionIndicator.setMessage(message);
        }
    }

    public static void dismissActionIndicator() {
        if (actionIndicator != null && actionIndicator.isShowing()) {
            try {
                actionIndicator.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            actionIndicator = null;
            System.out.println("Dialog dismissed");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void showAlerDialog(Context context, String title,
        String msg, AlertDialogDelegate delegate, int code) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(ERROR)) {
        alertDialog.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.error_icon));
    } else if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(SUCCESS)) {
        alertDialog.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.success));
    } else {
        alertDialog.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.warning));
    }

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new AlertDialogListenter(delegate,
            code));
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Then call AlertDialog like

ClassName.showAlerDialog(context,title,msg,delegate,code);

here context --> Context

title --> alertdialog title -- String

msg ---> alertdialog msg -- String

delegate ---> Object of interface which call a function on some yes -- no event

code -- integer -- for some different action on delegate

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void showAlerDialog(Context context, String title,
        String msg, AlertDialogDelegate delegate, int code) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setMessage(msg);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(ERROR)) {
        alertDialog.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.error_icon));
    } else if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(SUCCESS)) {
        alertDialog.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.success));
    } else {
        alertDialog.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.warning));
    }

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new AlertDialogListenter(delegate,
            code));
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Comment: Please provide description in answer.